# Is there a lower cost operation than std::copy to copy a uint8_t* data to a vector of type uint8_t?

Tags: stdvector, uint8array, stdcopy

Recently I wrote a c++ code and I used a function from an external library. the type of one of the arguments of this function is std::vector, but my data is in a variable named payload, which it's type is const uint8_t*. so I copied my payload data into a vector with std::copy like below:

std::vector my_vector;
std::copy(payload, payload + length, back_inserter(my_vector));

because of calling so much of this code, I'm in search for a lower cost operation to copy my payload data into my_vector variable in order to prepare input argument of the function which I used in my code.
is there any way to this purpose?

Comment: Could you use a vector of type <uint8_t*> ?

Comment: If i change the implementation of function, i can use vector of <uint8_t*> instead.
so , after that?

Comment: After that there is no need for a copy. Your memory will not be contiguous but your pointers will.  Much faster than copying.

Comment: Thank you. and if i couldn't change type of arguments in function, is there any other way?

Comment: You could try using std::move but that Just casts a pointer to a uint8_t, so it’s basically the same thing.